# How can I make my code more optimized?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

This is the code for my android game I am trying to make:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.display.MovieClip;


var STATE_INIT_GAME:String = "STATE_INIT_GAME";
var STATE_PLAY_GAME:String = "STATE_PLAY_GAME";
var STATE_END_GAME:String = "STATE_END_GAME";
var gameState:String;
var hearts:Array;
var atoms:Array;
var bombs:Array;
var enemies:Array;
var level:Number;
var score:Number;
var lives:Number;
var tempHeart:MovieClip;
var tempBomb:MovieClip;
var tempAtom:MovieClip;
var tempEnemy:MovieClip;
var rSound:rMusic = new rMusic  ;
var Rchannel:SoundChannel;
var offset:int = 20;
var enemyBaseSpeed:int = 4;
var speedLevelInc:Number = 3;
var MAX_SPEED:Number = 100;
score = 0;
roachLevel.score_txt.text = String(score);

function gameLoopR(e:Event):void
{
    switch (gameState)
    {
        case STATE_INIT_GAME :
            initGame();
            break;
        case STATE_PLAY_GAME :
            playGame();
            break;
        case STATE_END_GAME :
            endGame();
            break;
    }
}
function initGame():void
{

    Rchannel = rSound.play(0,9999);
    level = 1;
    roachLevel.level_txt.text = String(level);
    lives = 3;
    roachLevel.lives_txt.text = String(lives);
    hearts = new Array();
    bombs = new Array();
    atoms = new Array();
    enemies = new Array();
    gameState = STATE_PLAY_GAME;
}
function playGame():void
{

    makeEnemies();
    moveEnemies();
    makeHearts();
    moveHearts();
    makeBombs();
    moveBombs();
    makeAtoms();
    moveAtoms();
    testForEnd();
}
function makeBombs():void
{
    var chance:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6000);
    if (chance <=  +  level)
    {
        tempBomb.scaleX = 1.5;
        tempBomb.scaleY = 1.5;
        tempBomb = new Bomb();
        tempBomb.x = Math.round(Math.random() * 480);
        tempBomb.cacheAsBitmap = true;
        addChild(tempBomb)
        bombs.push(tempBomb);
        tempBomb.speed = 1;
    }
}

function moveBombs():void
{
    var tempBomb:MovieClip;

    for (var h:int =bombs.length-1; h>=0; h--)
    {

        tempBomb = bombs[h];
        if (tempBomb.dead)
        {
            Rchannel.stop();
            lives = 0;
            roachLevel.level_txt.text = String(lives);
            bombs.splice(h,1);
        }
        else
        {
            tempBomb.rotation += (Math.round(Math.random()*.4));
            tempBomb.y +=  (Math.cos((Math.PI/180)*tempBomb.rotation))*tempBomb.speed;
            if (tempBomb.x < 10)
            {
                tempBomb.x = 11;
            }
            if (tempBomb.x > stage.stageWidth - offset)
            {
                tempBomb.x = stage.stageWidth - offset;
            }
            if (tempBomb.y > stage.stageHeight)
            {
                removeBomb(h);

            }
        }
    }
}
function makeEnemies():void
{
    var chance:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 150);
    if (chance <= level && enemies.length < 4)
    {
        tempEnemy = new Enemy();
        tempEnemy.x = Math.round(Math.random() * 480);
        tempEnemy.cacheAsBitmap = true;
        addChild(tempEnemy);
        tempEnemy.scaleX = 1.5;
        tempEnemy.scaleY = 1.5;
        enemies.push(tempEnemy);

        tempEnemy.speed = enemyBaseSpeed + ((level - 1) * speedLevelInc);
        if (tempEnemy.speed > MAX_SPEED)
        {
            tempEnemy.speed = MAX_SPEED;

        }


    }

}

function moveEnemies():void
{
    var tempEnemy:MovieClip;


    for (var i:int =enemies.length-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        tempEnemy = enemies[i];
        if (tempEnemy.dead)
        {
            score++;
            score++;
            roachLevel.score_txt.text = String(score);
            enemies.splice(i,1);

        }
        else
        {

            tempEnemy.rotation += (Math.round(Math.random()*.4));
            tempEnemy.y +=  (Math.cos((Math.PI/180)*tempEnemy.rotation))*tempEnemy.speed;
            if (tempEnemy.x < 10)
            {
                tempEnemy.x = 11;
            }
            if (tempEnemy.x > stage.stageWidth - offset)
            {
                tempEnemy.x = stage.stageWidth - offset;
            }
            if (tempEnemy.y > stage.stageHeight)
            {
                removeEnemy(i);

                lives--;
                roachLevel.lives_txt.text = String(lives);
            }
        }
    }
}
function makeHearts():void
{
    var chance:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8000);
    if (chance <=  +  level)
    {
        tempHeart = new Heart();
        tempHeart.x = Math.round(Math.random() * 480);
        tempHeart.cacheAsBitmap = true;
        addChild(tempHeart);
        tempHeart.scaleX = 1.5;
        tempHeart.scaleY = 1.5;
        hearts.push(tempHeart);

        tempHeart.speed = enemyBaseSpeed + ((level - 1) * speedLevelInc);
    }
}
function moveHearts():void
{
    var tempHeart:MovieClip;

    for (var k:int =hearts.length-1; k>=0; k--)
    {

        tempHeart = hearts[k];
        if (tempHeart.dead)
        {
            lives++;
            roachLevel.lives_txt.text = String(lives);
            hearts.splice(k,1);
        }
        else
        {
            tempHeart.rotation += (Math.round(Math.random()*.4));
            tempHeart.y +=  (Math.cos((Math.PI/180)*tempHeart.rotation))*tempHeart.speed;
            if (tempHeart.x < 10)
            {
                tempHeart.x = 11;
            }
            if (tempHeart.x > stage.stageWidth - offset)
            {
                tempHeart.x = stage.stageWidth - offset;
            }
            if (tempHeart.y > stage.stageHeight)
            {
                removeHeart(k);
            }
        }
    }
}

function makeAtoms():void
{
    var chance:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7500);
    if (chance <=  +  level)
    {
        tempAtom = new Atom();
        tempAtom.x = Math.round(Math.random() * 480);
        tempAtom.cacheAsBitmap = true;
        addChild(tempAtom);
        tempAtom.scaleX = 1.5;
        tempAtom.scaleY = 1.5;
        atoms.push(tempAtom);
        tempAtom.speed = enemyBaseSpeed + ((level - 1) * speedLevelInc);
    }
}


function moveAtoms():void
{
    var tempAtom:MovieClip;

    for (var c:int =atoms.length-1; c>=0; c--)
    {

        tempAtom = atoms[c];
        if (tempAtom.dead)
        {
            score++;
            score++;
            score++;
            score++;
            score++;
            roachLevel.score_txt.text = String(score);
            atoms.splice(c,1);
        }
        else
        {
            tempAtom.rotation += (Math.round(Math.random()*.4));
            tempAtom.y +=  (Math.cos((Math.PI/180)*tempAtom.rotation))*tempAtom.speed;
            if (tempAtom.x < 10)
            {
                tempAtom.x = 11;
            }
            if (tempAtom.x > stage.stageWidth - offset)
            {
                tempAtom.x = stage.stageWidth - offset;
            }
            if (tempAtom.y > stage.stageHeight)
            {
                removeAtom(c);

            }
        }
    }
}
function removeEnemy(id:int)
{

    removeChild(enemies[id]);
    enemies.splice(id,1);
}
function removeHeart(kd:int)
{

    removeChild(hearts[kd]);
    hearts.splice(kd,1);
}
function removeBomb(hd:int)
{

    removeChild(bombs[hd]);
    bombs.splice(hd,1);
}
function removeAtom(cd:int)
{

    removeChild(atoms[cd]);
    atoms.splice(cd,1);
}
function testForEnd():void
{
    if (score > level * 20)
    {
        level++;
        roachLevel.level_txt.text = String(level);
    }
    if (lives == 0)
    {
        gameState = STATE_END_GAME;
    }

}
function endGame():void
{
    removeGame();
    roachLevel.visible = false;
    Menu_mc.visible = false;
    endscreen_mc.visible = true;
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoopR);
    showresults();

}
function removeGame():void
{
    for (var i:int = enemies.length-1; i >=0; i--)
    {
        removeEnemy(i);
    }
    for (var h:int = bombs.length-1; h >=0; h--)
    {
        removeBomb(h);
    }
    for (var k:int = hearts.length-1; k >=0; k--)
    {
        removeHeart(k);
    }
    for (var c:int = atoms.length-1; c >=0; c--)
    {
        removeAtom(c);
    }
}
```

The game works perfectly on Android and everything works. There is one problem though. The game gets laggy and the enemies get harder to click when the enemies' speed increases.
This is the code for the enemies. It is a movie clip that gets added on to the stage by actionscript.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import fl.motion.Animator;
import flash.events.*;
play();
var mysound:squish = new squish(); 
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, kill);
this.dead = false;
function kill(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    this.dead=true;
    mouseChildren=false
    mysound.play();
    gotoAndPlay(21);
    this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, kill);
    flash.utils.setTimeout(removeSelf,2000);

}

function removeSelf():void
{
    this.parent.removeChild(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code I'd guess that your biggest performance win would be to implement 'Object Pooling' for entities that get created in the game loop.

Two of the most expensive operations are creating objects (with the 'new' operator) and garbage collection (when you remove something and the app decides to clear the memory it was using).

The idea behind Object Pools is to create a bunch of objects upfront and reuse them throughout the game so that you eliminate both object creation and garbage collection.

So in your case, for example where you create and destroy enemies you get a performance penalty every time you call 'new Enemy()' and another one when the old enemy is removed.

With object pooling you would essentially do 'new Enemy()' a few times on the start screen and then just reuse those same objects throughout the game. You'll replace tempEnemy = new Enemy(); with tempEnemy = ObjectPool.get(Enemy); or similar and when you do the removeChild(enemies[id]); you'll also do ObjectPool.dispose(enemies[id]); so that it gets put back in the pool for reuse.

It sounds complicated but it's actually really easy and simple to implement. I just found an old Lee Brimelow video that should explain how to implement it: http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=160